# How can I ensure nonbreaking spaces before every citation in pandoc markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, typesetting

Let's take this example:

- **test.md:**

  ```
  ---
  bibliography: test.bib
  ---

  This is just a test text to demonstrate that in some situations, unfortunately, citations will appear at the beginning of a line, which is often considered unaesthetic [@dominici2014overview].
  ```
- **test.bib:**

  ```
  @article{dominici2014overview,
      title={An overview of Pandoc},
      author={Dominici, Massimiliano},
      journal={TUGboat},
      volume={35},
      number={1},
      pages={44--50},
      year={2014}
  }
  ```
- **acm.csl:** http://www.zotero.org/styles/association-for-computing-machinery

Build:

```
pandoc test.md --citeproc --csl=acm.csl --bibliography=test.bib --pdf-engine=pdflatex -o test.pdf
```

This renders the PDF as:

[image: This is just a test text to demonstrate that in some situations, unfortunately, cita-LINEBREAKtions will appear at the beginning of a line, which is often considered unaestheticLINEBREAK1.LINEBREAK1 Massimiliano Dominici. 2014. An overview of pandoc. TUGboat 35, 1LINEBREAK(2014), 44–50.]

(Note that the `[1]` stands at its own line.)

How can I make sure that there is a nonbreaking space before the `[1]` so that it does not appear alone in the line? The obvious solution would be to use a `\`  instead of a simple   in the Markdown, but this would clutter my Markdown file, so I'm looking for an automatic solution such as a configuration or a pandoc filter instead.

I even tried to write a simple filter, but apparently, the nonbreaking space is ignored, and this would require me to handle special cases such as the beginning of the sentence, so I would prefer an existing solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandocfilters as pf

def add_nonbreaking_space(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Cite':
        value[1] = [{**text, 'c': f"\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}{text['c']}"} for text in value[1]]
        return pf.Cite(*value)
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pf.toJSONFilter(add_nonbreaking_space)
```